# multiprocessing.Queue deadlocks after "reader" process death

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

I've been playing with multiprocessing package and noticed that queue can be deadlocked for reading when:

1. The "reader" process is using [get](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get) with *timeout* > 0:

   ```
   self.queue.get(timeout=3)
   ```
2. "reader" dies while [get](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get) is blocking due to *timeout*.

After that queue is locked forever.

#### Application demonstrating the problem

I create two child processes "Worker" (putting into queue) and "Receiver" (getting from queue). Also parent process periodically checks if his children [are alive](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) and starts new child if needed.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing
import procname
import time

class Receiver(multiprocessing.Process):
    ''' Reads from queue with 3 secs timeout '''

    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        procname.setprocname('Receiver')
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get(timeout=3)
                print '<<< `{}`, queue rlock: {}'.format(
                    msg, self.queue._rlock)
            except multiprocessing.queues.Empty:
                print '<<< EMPTY, Queue rlock: {}'.format(
                    self.queue._rlock)
                pass


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    ''' Puts into queue with 1 sec sleep '''

    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        procname.setprocname('Worker')
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~{}'.format(
                self.queue.qsize())
            self.queue.put('msg from Worker')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    worker = Worker(queue)
    worker.start()

    receiver = Receiver(queue)
    receiver.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if not worker.is_alive():
            print 'Restarting worker'
            worker = Worker(queue)
            worker.start()
        if not receiver.is_alive():
            print 'Restarting receiver'
            receiver = Receiver(queue)
            receiver.start()
```

#### How processes tree looks like in *ps*

```
bash
 \_ python queuetest.py
     \_ Worker
     \_ Receiver
```

#### Console output

```
$ python queuetest.py
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~0
<<< `msg from Worker`, queue rlock: <Lock(owner=None)>
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~0
<<< `msg from Worker`, queue rlock: <Lock(owner=None)>
Restarting receiver                        <-- killed Receiver with SIGTERM
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~0
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~1
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~2
<<< EMPTY, Queue rlock: <Lock(owner=SomeOtherProcess)>
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~3
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~4
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~5
<<< EMPTY, Queue rlock: <Lock(owner=SomeOtherProcess)>
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~6
Worker: putting msg, Queue size: ~7
```

Is there any way to bypass this? Using [get_nowait](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get_nowait) combined with sleep seems to be some kind of workaround but it does not read the data "as it comes".

#### System information

```
$ uname -sr
Linux 3.11.8-200.fc19.x86_64

$ python -V
Python 2.7.5

In [3]: multiprocessing.__version__
Out[3]: '0.70a1'
```

#### "it just works" solution

While writing this question I came up with some silly modification to Receiver class:

```python
class Receiver(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        procname.setprocname('Receiver')
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            while True:
                try:
                    msg = self.queue.get_nowait()
                    print '<<< `{}`, queue rlock: {}'.format(
                        msg, self.queue._rlock)
                except multiprocessing.queues.Empty:
                    print '<<< EMPTY, Queue rlock: {}'.format(
                        self.queue._rlock)
                    break
```

But it doesn't seem very good to me.

Comment: There is a [python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue20527) with a response "This is expected.".

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because *not_empty.release()* from *Queue.get()* never happends (the proccess has been killed already). Did you try to catch the TERM signal in Receiver and release the Queue mutex before exiting?

Comment: You mean **_rlock.release()** (this one is used in Queue.get AFAIK)?  No I have not tried catching any signals because I was thinking more about Receiver crashing due to an error not "gentle" signal which indeed can be handled.

Comment: As another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700299/mutex-in-shared-memory-when-one-user-crashes) pointed, the proper solution is to use the 'robust mutexes' or 'named semaphores'. I would recommend you to report a bug in multiprocessing library.